# Can we merge [gui-testing] into [ui-testing]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags for [gui-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui-testing) (192) and [ui-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-testing) (500) are very similar to each other in their descriptions and usage.

> gui-testing (Graphical user interface testing) is a type of software
>   testing that focuses on graphical user interfaces. - [gui-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui-testing)

> User interface testing is defined as to test the interface between the
>   application and the end user. - [ui-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-testing)

Can we merge these two tags together?

Comment: Except not every UI is specifically a GUI. Not to mention, NUI and OUI (natural and organic) will be more frequent as the technology becomes more widespread and accessible.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, I disagree with this request. GUI != UI. I wouldn't like to go further in it, but just quote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191859) good answer:

> GUI is "graphical user interface" and UI is just "user interface." GUI is a subset of UI. UI can include non-graphical interfaces such as screen readers or command line interfaces which aren't considered GUI.

Summarising, not all UIs are graphical, some may be non-graphical.

The tags do not have the same meaning, therefore they should not be synonymized and merged.